# Change ownership of VMware Fusion shared folder

Tags: 13.04, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to create a soft link of my Dropbox shared folder with:

```
ln -s Dropbox ~/Desktop
```

But I am not being successful. The link is created, but is broken and I can't access the folder through it.

[image: 1]

When I run `ls -la` in `/mnt/hgfs` I get this:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    4192 Nov 14 17:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Nov 14 16:06 ..
drwx------ 1  501 dialout  782 Nov 14 13:10 Dropbox
```

What is user 501?

I tried changing the ownership of the folder to my user and to root, but none seems to work. Shouldn't root be able to change any File or Directory ownership to itself?

```
chown -R root:root Dropbox
chown: changing ownership of ‘Dropbox’: Operation not permitted
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does VmWare Fusion have to do with this?

Comment: Maybe the user created 501 has something to do with it?

Answer (score 5):

Use this fix: http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2013/07/vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared.html

This should be a more permanent fix.

1. `sudo vim /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh`
2. Search for `vmhgfs_mnt="/mnt/hgfs"`. After this line add:

   ```sh
   vmuser=${VMWARE_MNT_USER:-root}
   ```
3. Then search for `vmware_exec_selinux "mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ $vmhgfs_mnt"` and replace it with following section:

   ```sh
   uid=`id --user $vmuser`
   gid=`id --group $vmuser`
   vmware_exec_selinux "mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ $vmhgfs_mnt -o uid=$uid,gid=$gid"
   ```
4. `sudo vim /etc/init/vmware-tools.conf`

   Before the `pre-start` and `post-stop` lines add:

   ```sh
   env VMWARE_MNT_USER=[The guest user you want]
   ```
5. `sudo reboot`

NOTE: This will have to be redone when you update/reinstall `vmware-tools`.

Comment: Please include the gist of the answer here, in your own words.

Answer (score 4):

I'm now using Fusion 8.5, and there's no `services.sh` any more

Open `/etc/init.d/vmware-tools` then find and edit the following block (see the `uid` and `gid`)

```
# Mount all hgfs filesystems
vmware_mount_vmhgfs() {
  if [ "`is_vmhgfs_mounted`" = "no" ]; then
    if [ "`vmware_vmhgfs_use_fuse`" = "yes" ]; then
      mkdir -p $vmhgfs_mnt
      vmware_exec_selinux "$vmdb_answer_BINDIR/vmhgfs-fuse \
         -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 $vmhgfs_mnt"
    else
      vmware_exec_selinux "mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ $vmhgfs_mnt -o uid=1000,gid=1000"
    fi
  fi
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, changing the ownership to the user normally logged in.. Wonderful!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo chown -R YOUR-USER-NAME:YOUR-USER-NAME Dropbox
```

Comment: That does not work.
` chmod: invalid mode`

Comment: I have done a mistake. It should be `chown` not `chmod`. I edited the answer